# Google Chrome for macOS: How to bypass "This type of file may harm your computer" and save file automatically

Tags: macos, google-chrome, dmg

Every time I download a .DMG file using Google Chrome, I have to open the Downloads tab and manually keep it which is super annoying. It shows **This type of file may harm your computer** message. Is there any way to always keep them?

Previously it can be configured in the settings but it seems there is no such setting in the latest version of Google Chrome.

Comment: What is the version of macOS and Google Chrome that you are running?

Comment: @NimeshNeema Chrome: Version 73.0.3683.103 (Official Build) (64-bit). macOS Mojave 10.14.5

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome uses heuristics to determine if a file could be harmful and alerts you likewise. In such cases, user has to click on the keep button shown alongside the active download in the bottom toolbar, or navigate to the Downloads tab and click on keep button. This may have to be done for one or more active downloads.

Keeping security in mind, Google Chrome doesn't provide a setting which completely turn-off this behavior. One workaround this is to enable Chrome to ask you for the location to save the file.

Access Google Chrome Settings, via the **Customise and control Google Chrome** button located at the end of the address bar, or use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>. Scroll to the end and click on **Advanced**. Now under Downloads section, enable **Ask where to save each file before downloading**.

[image]

If you generally choose to save all the downloaded files to a particular location, this will necessitate an extra step where you'll have to confirm the download location.

However, this will benefit by you as browser will bring to your attention any download activity. You can choose to discard any unintended file and can choose to save them to a custom location directly.

Also, it's a good idea to always keep your browser up-to-date from security standpoint.